# Is there a ZPAQ implementaion that integrates with GUI compressors like File-Roller?

Tags: linux, compression

I've tried a number of ZPAQ implementations for Linux, but I don't like that they are all command-line programs, and thus require a lot of typing to get simple things done. My file browser supports compression of files and folders with a "compress..." option in the context menu, but the formats I can choose from are less effective than ZPAQ. The only program with ZPAQ support that showed up on this list was lrzip, but lrzip uses the LZMA algorithm when used this way.

Is there a program that I can install to allow ZPAQ compression from the context menu, or a way to make my File-Roller clone (Engrampa) run lrzip in ZPAQ mode?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is easy if you use linux like lupu-528*.iso LiveCD it uses build in
xarchiver [old version] which have wrapper scripts for every archive type
if you go to directory /usr/local/lib/xarchiver/wrappers/ you see files like
7za-wrap.sh and you can write many more copy rename modify it and this
xarchiver show this compression mode

and if you like use midnight commander almost the same use F2 for menu

and if you need file-roller it have only isoinfo.sh so you may need
new stable compilled version in debian package is ok for it

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that `lrzip` reads a configuration file called `lrzip.conf` from the working directory, `/etc/lrzip`, or `~/.lrzip`. Among other things, this configuration file can set the default algorithm to use. It's not the most elegant solution, but it allows right-click creation of ZPAQ archives as I requested.

source: http://linux.die.net/man/5/lrzip.conf

Comment: It seems that the configuration file doesn't apply to `lrztar`, and Engrampa apparently passes an argument to set LZMA as the algorithm, crashing the program.